# Работа с aiogram3 и aioschedule

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, schedule

Пишу бота на aiogram3. Мне нужно отправлять сообщение всем юзерам каждую неделю во вторник в определенное время. Но не один из приложенных ниже вариантов кода просто не помогает.
**Первый пример:**

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize bot
        self.bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
        self.dp = Dispatcher(bot=self.bot)

        self.users_service: UsersService = UsersService()


    def get_routers(self):
        self.dp.include_router(users_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(support_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(random_coffee_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(events_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(residents_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(contacts_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(about_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(profile_router.router)

        self.dp.include_router(admins_router.router)

    def start(self):
        self.get_routers()
        self.dp.run_polling(self.bot)


async def random_coffee():
    try:
        print('random_coffee')
        main: Main = Main()

        users = main.users_service.get_users_for_cron()

        random_num = random.randint(0, len(users) - 1)

        for i in range(len(users)):
            await main.bot.send_message(chat_id=users[i][1],
                                        text=f"*[Random Coffee]*\n\n"
                                             f"{users[random_num][5]}\n"
                                             f"*Бизнес:* {users[random_num][7]}\n"
                                             f"*Хобби:* {users[random_num][8]}\n"
                                             f"*Запрос:* {users[random_num][9]}\n"
                                             f"*Ресурсы:* {users[random_num][10]}\n"
                                             f"*[https://t.me/{users[random_num][2]}]*\n\n"
                                             f"#земляки", parse_mode='Markdown')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error while random_coffee: {e}')


def cron_task():
    job = random_coffee()
    schedule.every().tuesday.at("22:25").do(job)


async def cron():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=cron_task)
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.create_task(cron())

    main = Main()
    main.start()
```

**Второй пример:**

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize bot
        self.bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
        self.dp = Dispatcher(bot=self.bot)

        self.users_service: UsersService = UsersService()


    def get_routers(self):
        self.dp.include_router(users_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(support_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(random_coffee_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(events_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(residents_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(contacts_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(about_router.router)
        self.dp.include_router(profile_router.router)

        self.dp.include_router(admins_router.router)

    def start(self):
        self.get_routers()
        self.dp.run_polling(self.bot)


async def random_coffee():
    try:
        print('random_coffee')
        main: Main = Main()

        users = main.users_service.get_users_for_cron()

        random_num = random.randint(0, len(users) - 1)

        for i in range(len(users)):
            await main.bot.send_message(chat_id=users[i][1],
                                        text=f"*[Random Coffee]*\n\n"
                                             f"{users[random_num][5]}\n"
                                             f"*Бизнес:* {users[random_num][7]}\n"
                                             f"*Хобби:* {users[random_num][8]}\n"
                                             f"*Запрос:* {users[random_num][9]}\n"
                                             f"*Ресурсы:* {users[random_num][10]}\n"
                                             f"*[https://t.me/{users[random_num][2]}]*\n\n"
                                             f"#земляки", parse_mode='Markdown')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error while random_coffee: {e}')


async def cron():
    job = await random_coffee()
    aioschedule.every().tuesday.at("22:16").do(job)

    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def cron_task():
    await asyncio.create_task(cron())

task = cron_task()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.create_task(cron_task())

    main = Main()
    main.start()
```

При использовании двух вариантов бот просто падает, без отправки сообщения, и выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'cron' was never awaited
```

Пытался писать вот так:
[image: Третий пример:]

При таком подходе бот отправляет сообщение сразу после запуска, независимо от текущего времени (даже если оно больше или меньше нужного) и ложится вот с такой ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]